# test hibernate entities with spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit, entity

I try to tests how hibernate Entities are persisted to database. I have 5 tests for 3 Entitites. All my attempts are unsuccessful((( I tried to use @Transactional annotation to bind each test to one transaction. But I could not (tried all combinations). Now I try to test it manually creating sessions and transactions. But now problem is that I dont know how to create one session for all tests. I tried *@BeforeClass*, but here problem is that it is static and I use Spring beans for session creation. Any ideas how I can test hibernate Entities?

Comment: Spring is quite well documented. Read the manual. If you're still stuck, then post your code, tell us what you expect it to do, and what it does instead. The only possible answer to your question, as is, is to regurgitate the Spring documentation, which is useless.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use a dedicated database like HSQLDB for testing you entities via DAO test classes.**

You will need a:

- Maven test profile
- Spring configuration file (test context)
- Script SQL to insert some data
- DAO class test.

**Maven test profile :**

```
<profile>
    <id>test</id>
    <properties>
        <jpa.dialect>org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect</jpa.dialect>
        <jpa.vendor.adapter>HibernateJpaVendorAdapter</jpa.vendor.adapter>
        <jdbc.dialect>org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</jdbc.dialect>
        <jdbc.url>jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDatabase</jdbc.url>
        <jdbc.driver>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</jdbc.driver>
        <jdbc.username>sa</jdbc.username>
        <jdbc.password></jdbc.password>
        <jdbc.format_sql>true</jdbc.format_sql>
        <jdbc.show_sql>true</jdbc.show_sql>
        <!-- import.sql is read : it must have this name and be in classpath -->
        <jpa.generateDdl>true</jpa.generateDdl>
        <hibernate.format_sql>true</hibernate.format_sql>
        <hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>create</hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

**Spring test-applicationContext.xml file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- enables interpretation of the @PersistenceUnit/@PersistenceContext 
        annotations providing convenient access to EntityManagerFactory/EntityManager -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="foo.bar.dao">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jpaLibrary" />
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="${jpa.dialect}" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.${jpa.vendor.adapter}">
                <property name="showSql" value="${jdbc.show_sql}" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="${jdbc.dialect}" />
                <!-- On genere la BDD au demarrage -->
                <property name="generateDdl" value="${jpa.generateDdl}" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <context:spring-configured />
    <context:annotation-config />

</beans>
```

**import.sql (authors for instance):**

```
INSERT INTO `testDatabase`.`authors`(author_id, name) VALUES
(1, "JRR Tolkien"),
(2, "Albert Camus"),
(3, "Victor Hugo");
...
```

**Finally, the class to test your DAO (then entities) :**

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import foo.bar.dao.BookDao;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/test-applicationContext.xml" })
public class BookDaoTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private BookDao bookDao;

    private int initialSize = 0;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        initialSize = bookDao.findAll().size();
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllBooks() {
        assertEquals(12, initialSize);
    }

    ...
}
```